# Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0. Required by: project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.1.0

Tags: java, android

I'm try to install paypalcheckout sdk in andorid project from below link,

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/android/

I'm also adding this to dependencies in gradle app module file
implementation 'com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0' & rebuild project but it won't be able to build

In project gradle file code

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    maven {
        url  "https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android"
        credentials {
            // Be sure to add these non-sensitive credentials in order to retrieve dependencies from
            // the private repository.
            username 'paypal_sgerritz'
            password 'AKCp8jQ8tAahqpT5JjZ4FRP2mW7GMoFZ674kGqHmupTesKeAY2G8NcmPKLuTxTGkKjDLRzDUQ'
        }
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

}

when I build android project it says error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.1.0
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.1.0
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0 > com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I'm new to android.Suggest me some solution to solve this.

Comment: Can you please share your app Level build.gradle ?

Comment: I guess you are missing something in app level build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing to add dependencies in your app level build.gradle

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.1.0'
```